# Analysis for Engineers: Where Do You Start?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, soft-question, numerical-methods

Having taken none of the prerequisite rigorous treatments of mathematics during my undergrad years, I feel at a disadvantage to the people in my major what *do* have that analysis/abstract math background, I always find myself struggling to understand those more rigorous papers that use concepts from real/complex analysis, topology, set theory and the slew of abstract math concepts that you don't typically see in engineering at an undergrad level.

What sources are especially good for starting to understand more rigorous math and why are they good?

I specifically deal with controls, stability of dynamical systems and probability, so any books that are especially good for those fields are even better.

Comment: Uh oh. I thought engineers used calculus, and that analysis was only for math majors. When/How is real and/or complex analysis used in engineering? I'm currently working on an undergrad degree in electrical engineering, with a minor in computer science. Should I take some analysis courses?

Comment: @waveslider: I'm a graduate student that mostly does math related work. Although I'm not the strongest in analysis, I do need it to some extent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know much more about Analysis than I read on Wikipedia, although I've just begun reading Introduction to Calculus and Analysis I, by Richard Courant. My understanding is that Analysis is mostly concerned with Calculus topics on a much more rigorous level: mainly the study of proofs for the theorems and concepts that comprise Calculus. If that is true, how are proofs applied to real-world, practical problems? I guess I'm either confused in my understanding of what Analysis is, or don't understand how mathematic proofs are useful in a practical way.

Comment: @waveslider: I don't think I'm the best person to ask this, as I myself was asking a question on the topic! haha, my suggestion is to post an independent question on here and see what people say. If you do, please comment with a link so I can see the answers too!

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the advice, though.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it would be best just take a course in proof writing, and real and complex analyses...

at my instituition we use

"Fundamentals of Complex Analyses with applications to engineering and science" 3rd edition: EB staff, AD Snider

"Introduction to Real Analyses": Robert G Bartle, Donald R Sherbert 4th edition

google practice problems if nothing else, there can normally be some archives for the past exams or quizes with solns so that you can know if you do it correctly.

hope this helps some